# postgresql searching by string array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, csv

We have a table where one column(varchar) contains strings separated by space like below

```
A.Y A.P F.K
AC.YZ AB.YY
Ap.YZ BC.YZ
```

I would like to search with `A.P A.Y F.K` and result should return first row.

I am trying to find a way to split by space and sort and compare the resulting array with the input which is also sorted after splitting in same way.

There is a function `string_to_array(<input/column>, ' ')` that can be used to split but couldn't find any way to sort the resulting string array. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort the array, you can use the contains operator `@>`

```
where string_to_array(the_column, ' ') @> array['A.P', 'F.K', 'A.Y']
```

This return rows that *contain* the array on the right hand side, i.e. the column might contain additional elements. e.g. `A.P A.Z A.Y F.K`  would also match.

If you want to find the rows that contain *exactly* those three elements you can use the contains operator in both directions:

```
where string_to_array(the_column, ' ') @> array['A.P', 'F.K', 'A.Y']
  and string_to_array(the_column, ' ') <@ array['A.P', 'F.K', 'A.Y']
```